# How to use params.(key) to get specific data for each route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to build a car list app that will show a list of cars, and when I click on a car's details button, it will route it to another component/page that will show the details of cars.
I can get the key (vin for me) but I want to get the details of the car for each key(vin) on this page.It's like http://localhost:3000/cars/WAUZZZ4G6FN052847= key. So when a car's key will show up, all details will come due to their key number. Thank you.

index.html

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Outlet, } from "react-router-dom";
import DummyComponent from "./components/DummyComponent";
import CarDetails from "./pages/CarDetails";
import { Home } from "@mui/icons-material";
import Cars from "./pages/Cars";



const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(


  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
      <Route path="/cars" element={<Outlet />} >
        <Route path="list" element={<Cars />} />
        <Route path=":vin" element={<CarDetails />} />
      </Route>
      <Route path="Home" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="DummyComponent" element={<DummyComponent />} />

    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>

);
```

Cars.js

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import List from '@mui/material/List';
import ListItem from '@mui/material/ListItem';
import ListItemButton from '@mui/material/ListItemButton';
import ListItemText from '@mui/material/ListItemText';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";



const App = () => {


    const [cars, setCars] = useState([])
    const getCarData = async () => {
        try {
            const data = await axios.get("https://react-challenge-api.azurewebsites.net/vehicles")
            setCars(data.data)
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getCarData()
    }, [])
    return (

        <div className="App">

            <List sx={{ width: '100%', maxWidth: 600, bgcolor: 'background.paper' }}>
                {cars.map((car) => (

                    <ListItemButton key={car.vin}>
                        <ListItem
                            key={car.vin}
                            disableGutters

                            secondaryAction={
                                <ListItemButton >
                                    <Link to={`/cars/${car.vin}`}>details</Link>

                                </ListItemButton>
                            }
                        >
                            <ListItemText key={car.vin} primary={car.model_variant} />

                        </ListItem>
                    </ListItemButton>

                ))
                }
            </List >
        </div >
    );
};

export default App;
```

CarDetails.js (I want to show each data in this component, I used params but I don't know how to get data due to params.

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const CarDetails = () => {

    let params = useParams();

    return (
        <>
            <h1>car</h1>
            <ul>
                this is your {params.vin}
            </ul>
        </>
    )
}



export default CarDetails;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest moving the car data fetching into a layout route and pass the `cars` state down in an `Outlet` context.

Example:

Cars - Handles fetching the car data and passes the `cars` state along to nested routes via the `Outlet` component's context.

```
const Cars = () => {
  const [cars, setCars] = useState([]);

  const getCarData = async () => {
    try {
      const data = await axios.get(
        "https://react-challenge-api.azurewebsites.net/vehicles"
      );
      setCars(data.data);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getCarData();
  }, []);

  return <Outlet context={{ cars }} />;
};
```

CarList - Reads the `cars` state from the `Outlet` context and renders the list.

```
const CarList = () => {
  const { cars } = useOutletContext();

  return (
    <List sx={{ width: "100%", maxWidth: 600, bgcolor: "background.paper" }}>
      {cars.map((car) => (
        <ListItemButton key={car.vin}>
          <ListItem
            key={car.vin}
            disableGutters
            secondaryAction={
              <ListItemButton>
                <Link to={`/cars/${car.vin}`}>details</Link>
              </ListItemButton>
            }
          >
            <ListItemText key={car.vin} primary={car.model_variant} />
          </ListItem>
        </ListItemButton>
      ))}
    </List>
  );
};
```

CarDetails - Takes the `vin` route path param and the `cars` array from the outlet context and searches for a matching car object.

```
const CarDetails = () => {
  const { vin } = useParams();
  const { cars } = useOutletContext();

  const car = cars.find((car) => car.vin === vin);

  if (!car) {
    return "No car matches this VIN";
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h1>{car.model_variant}</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>Body: {car.body_type}</li>
        <li>Doors: {car.doors}</li>
        <li>Fuel: {car.fuel_type}</li>
        <li>VIN: {car.vin}</li>
        <li>Registration #: {car.regno}</li>
        <li>Transmission: {car.transmission_type}</li>
      </ul>
    </>
  );
};
```

Routes

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
  <Route path="/cars" element={<Cars />}> // <-- layout route renders outlet
    <Route path="list" element={<CarList />} />
    <Route path=":vin" element={<CarDetails />} />
  </Route>
  <Route path="Home" element={<Home />} />
  <Route path="DummyComponent" element={<DummyComponent />} />
</Routes>
```

[image: Edit how-to-use-params-key-to-get-specific-data-for-each-route]

Comment: It worked! I'm so sorry that I couldn't ask the question right before, but you answered it again! Thank you so much! Also, I'm trying to understand the process that you gave.

Comment: @Krina What that your question that I helped with previously? I saw that the code was familiar to something I had helped with recently but couldn't find any reference to it in my history or saved sandboxes. Glad to help. Cheers and good luck!

Comment: It was the same code but it was my first question so I couldn't provide enough code/info in question so the question is closed. I think that's why you couldn't get any info about the previous one.  Btw, can I fix this problem on other hand, by creating a dummy array and fetching data?

Comment: How can i fix this problem using redux-sagas? sorry for asking twice. This is a great solution but my friend says you should use redux-sagas.

Comment: @krina If your friend means to say you should use some global app state that is entirely up to you and your specific use case. If your code is nothing more than the above you asked about then IMHO it's not worth integrating Redux *just* to store the `cars` state. Once your app gains enough state that managing it in a single React context makes sense, then I'd suggest looking to [redux-toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) (RTK). It vastly improves on `react-redux` by minimizing the amount of boilerplate you need to write.

Comment: @krina I've not ever used `redux-saga`, but I can say that it's not a very popular library (*as compared to `react-redux` + `thunks` or RTK*). I've used RXJS/`redux-observables`/epics and can say that sagas have about the same amount of general appeal. After RTK was released it effectively made those other libraries obsolete. I'll never go back to them. This all said though, it is *only* my opinion. You may have different use cases and experience than I've had.

Comment: Well, he wants me to kinda-hire me for the project they building. And they are using redux-saga. So I should learn how to use it, and gain experience with them overthrowing my junior title. Thank you for your kind helps again :)

Comment: @krina Sorry to hear that. Best of luck to you!